# ie8 compatibility

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, click

I have some code that runs fine in Chrome and IE9. In IE8 browser, running compatibility mode, it breaks. The user base runs IE8 in compat mode. I put this in to force regular usage:
content="IE=edge

```
<form class="imei-block-radio" name="myForm">

      <input type="radio" name="blocktype" ng-model="actionType" value="block"        ng-click="changeBlock('block')" checked="true">  Block <br/> <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="blocktype" ng-model="actionType" value="unblock" ng-click="changeBlock('unblock')"> Un-Block <br/>

</form>
```

The code it hits is in a controller for the page and the code does get hit, but the input parameter is 'undefined'.

```
$scope.changeBlock = function(value) {
    alert(value);
    if (value == 'unblock')
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

The alert always shows that 'value' is always undefined. Also, other variables defined in the controller like:

```
$scope.actionType = 'block';
```

are also undefined inside the `changeBlock` function.

Comment: @Erik I'm having a similar problem.  Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: @Curt Unfortunately, I'm not the one having this problem. I only edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

ng-model seems not to work with input radio in IE8 and older.

This works for me:
`<input type="radio" ng-checked="actionType=='block'" ng-click="actionType='block'" name="blocktype" value="block">

<input type="radio" ng-checked="actionType=='unblock'" ng-click="actionType='block'" name="blocktype" value="unblock">`

Workaround: replace your ng-model with ng-check and ng-click

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->



<script>
  document.createElement('header');
  document.createElement('section');
  document.createElement('article');
  document.createElement('aside');
  document.createElement('nav');
  document.createElement('footer');
</script>




<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```